# Union of a family of pairwise distinct hyperplanes over an infinite field

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $\mathbb{k}$ be an infinite field and $V$ a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{k}$. I would like to show that for every family $P_1,\ldots,P_r$, $r\geq 2$, of pairwise distinct hyperplanes, there exists an element of $P_1$ which is not contained in $\bigcup_{2\leq i\leq r} P_i$.

I have already proven that $\bigcup_{1\leq i\leq r} P_i\subsetneq V$ and I was trying to show that $P_1\subset\bigcup_{2\leq i\leq r} P_i$ would imply $\bigcup_{2\leq i\leq r} P_i=V$ but I fail to get the contradiction.

Comment: $Q_i=(P_i\cap P)$ is a proper subspace of $P$, so the union over $i$ of the $Q_i$ can't be all of $P$.

Comment: Making any progress? Do you see what my comment is getting at?

Comment: It is clear now, thank you very much